# PHP-FPM crashes when having too many users while doing a heavy job

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a Server running Apache/2.2.22 (Debian), PHP 5.6.17 as FPM and MySQL 5.6.25.

The project runs using a CMS called Redaxo (I don't think it's that important, but I'll tell ya anyway). In Redaxo there are some functions which take some time (e.g. deleting cache and rebuilding it takes 1-2 minutes). In this time, when other users come on the website FPM crashes with a `500 Internal Server Error` and I have to reload the page multiple times until the Server Error disappears and the process is done.

I noticed that this only will happen if too many users are on the site on the same time and only when heavy operations are done.

10 users at the same time just surfing = No Problem
10 users at the same time just surfing, while cache deletion = 500 Error for everyone.

I checked this by disallowing the website for everyone except me (.htaccess deny/allow with ip). Then I did the heavy operation and had no problem. As soon as multiple people were on the site again, the problem was there again.

What could it be? What information do you need from me?

These values are set (not commented) in the `php-fpm.conf`

```
[global]
pid = /run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
emergency_restart_threshold = 0
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

These values are set (not commented) in the project specific `fpm.conf`

```
[projectname]
user = projectname
group = projectname

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm-projectname.sock
listen.owner = projectname
listen.group = projectname
listen.mode = 0660

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 150
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 30

chdir = /

php_value[upload_max_filesize] = 128M
php_value[max_post_size] = 128M
php_value[max_execution_time] = 180
php_value[memory_limit] = 256M
```

The script when it fails does much with MySQL and File creation if it helps? But it's pretty big, so I'm not sure if I should post it here? Or if it is even the problem?

The apache error log says either this

```
[Tue Feb 09 10:54:01 2016] [error] [client {IP}] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/fcgi-bin-php5-fpm-projectnmae" aborted: read failed
[Tue Feb 09 10:54:01 2016] [error] [client {IP}] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/fcgi-bin-php5-fpm-projectnmae"
```

or this

```
[Tue Feb 09 11:00:46 2016] [error] [client {IP}] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/fcgi-bin-php5-fpm-projectname"
[Tue Feb 09 11:00:48 2016] [error] [client {IP}] (104)Connection reset by peer: FastCGI: comm with server "/fcgi-bin-php5-fpm-projectname" aborted: read failed
```

The `fpm-log` says the following. Always different timings of course

```
[10-Feb-2016 09:40:59] WARNING: [pool projectname] child 10970 exited on signal 7 (SIGBUS) after 50.186611 seconds from start
[10-Feb-2016 09:40:59] NOTICE: [pool projectname] child 11092 started
```

Sometimes there's a warning like this in it

```
[09-Feb-2016 11:00:41] WARNING: [pool projectname] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 0 idle, and 6 total children
[09-Feb-2016 11:00:42] WARNING: [pool projectname] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 7 total children
```

Here are some more debug information

```
[18-Feb-2016 17:42:01] WARNING: [pool projectname] child 9088 exited on signal 7 (SIGBUS) after 70.130564 seconds from start
[18-Feb-2016 17:42:01] NOTICE: [pool projectname] child 9205 started
[18-Feb-2016 17:43:55] WARNING: [pool projectname] child 9099 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1181 in /var/www/projectname/htdocs/redaxo/include/classes/class.ooarticle.inc.php on line 44"
[18-Feb-2016 17:43:55] WARNING: [pool projectname] child 9099 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/projectname/htdocs/redaxo/include/classes/class.ooredaxo.inc.php on line 134"
[18-Feb-2016 17:43:55] WARNING: [pool projectname] child 9099 exited on signal 7 (SIGBUS) after 183.838886 seconds from start
[18-Feb-2016 17:43:55] NOTICE: [pool projectname] child 9330 started
[18-Feb-2016 17:44:00] WARNING: [pool projectname] child 9101 exited on signal 7 (SIGBUS) after 188.987954 seconds from start
[18-Feb-2016 17:44:00] NOTICE: [pool projectname] child 9336 started
```

Comment: Is there anything in apache and php-fpm  logs about the crashes?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add them. Give me one minute

Comment: Hey @max - I updated my post to add logs.

Comment: I would recommend you try to set also `pm.max_requests = 500`. It might help.

Comment: Also, there is a suggestion that it might be apc module. If so this setting might help `apc.stat = 0`

Comment: Hey. Thanks! Will forward this to my server provider. Let's see if it helps. I will come back later

Comment: Hi @max. My server administrator responded. We aren't using apc at all, and we have tried already setting `pm.max_requests` to 500. But this didn't work.

Comment: What triggers cache rebuild? Can it be moved to cli script?

Comment: My educated guess is your CPU runs at 100%(run `top` on server during cache rebuild) to fix it you might need to either 1 beef up server, 2 change cache rebuild code to use less resources.

Comment: I used to have a VM setup with php-fmp working under lighttpd. So every time that VM had to reprocess image(large file over 0.5gb) CPU would go 100% and web server would go irrespective for some time with similar error . Was not important for me as it was a stand alone app but not much you could do about it.

Comment: There's an unsolved bug report, stating that including a file that's beeing written at the moment could issue this error (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52752, still present in php7). You might want to set up a static cache, or set the page to maintenance mode.

Comment: We aren't including the file though, we only have `file_get_contents` for the file and `file_exists`, or does it count as the same?

Comment: I'm not sure about the internals. Might be affected too. During cache deletion, is the server at peak performance? I know it's difficult to hijack the caching mechanism, but a possible solution could be to write a long running script, that deletes the caches manually, one page at a time, at a slower pace. You could have some CPU left for users, but the cache rebuilding would take significantly longer. There are some hints for manual cache deletion here https://www.redaxo.org/de/wiki/index.php?n=R2.Caching (in german though)

Comment: Do you mean the mechanism in PHP or the server caching mechanism?

Comment: Which version of Redaxo are you running? You might want to look into that redaxo class that handles caching (since enabling that is when you start seeing 500's) you might get some insight there.. perhaps there's some operation causing some side effects that contribute to the 500

Comment: @E_p, we have many free resources. CPU usage is high but not at 100%

Comment: @Musterknabe During cache rebuild? Just track it during cache rebuild just for fun. It might be @ 99% that could "kill" lower/same priority processes.

Comment: Yeah, during cache rebuild. I can ask my server provider again how much the CPU usage is exactly.

Comment: @E_p I saw that the mysql cpu usage is over 100%. Could this be a problem?

Comment: It does not matter what process is t is. Without code or hardware changes you can try to play around with process priorities but that might create other issues.

Comment: Hm... So do you have any ideas how to determine where the problem is? (Hardware or software)?

Comment: @Musterknabe As I've mentioned I had similar problem with the some process running on a background at 98-100% CPU that would stop php-fpm serving pages. In your case during cache rebuild it can be MySQL (that runs at ~100%). So to make sure just check server processes during cache rebuild and see if anything runs @ close to 100%. If yes depending on what it is you can come up with list of solutions and make your decision on how to fix it. If no (that I doubt) you need to look somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` or not? that could probably errors messaging switched off, that brings 500. If you turn it on, you'll simply get php errors messages instead of 500.

Comment: If MySQL is high on CPU, do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to see what is running at that time.  Then we can discuss whether the queries are at fault.

Comment: If the web server is running out of resources, _decrease_ the number of web connections (eg, Apache MaxClients) that it allows -- this is to prevent the queries from stumbling over each other, and no one finishing.  (Ever been in a store with so many customers it is really difficult to get through the aisles?)

Comment: What is your cache deletion process ? Is it files in RAM, in FS, some other cache system ? Also, this 500 may happens if apache is too slow to answer, the connexion might be closed (network, firewall, stuff) and the browser therefore display a 500, which might be the issue since I read  "Connection reset by peer" and "Incomplete headers" in your logs. What is your FastCgiConfig idle-timeout ? Check your apache fcgi config

Comment: The problem is, that sometimes the error happens instance. I start the cache deletion process and instantly get a 500. So idle-timeout shouldn't be the problem here. For each article the cache is generated in files.

Comment: check your hard drive

Answer (score 3):

This might just be the effect of some lock issue from your MySQL server.

You have to connect to your MySQL host during the latency.

- If you can't connect, then you run out of the number of allowed concurrent connections of your MySQL server or your user
- If you can connect, you have to see what the mysql command "show processlist" returns. Now you have 2 choices:

  - Many "Waiting for query cache lock" : this will require that you change some of your MySQL server configuration. (*this can be caused by an oversized query cache*)
  - You have a request which takes all the resources, which you will have to optimize.

Comment: I'm connected while the process was running. I'll check for the latter

Comment: Hi, I have many requests, but their state is "Creating sort index". Nothing like "Waiting for query cache lock"

Comment: So you clearly fall in the last category. You have a request or a table which needs to be optimized. For those tables you have to define a multi column index starting with the columns used to sort, and ending with the column used to select/join. `ALTER TABLE x ADD INDEX(sort_column1, sort_column2, where_column1, where_column2, .)`

Comment: Hey Adam. The queries are coming from a CMS. And I already checked the database and the queries that are getting executed. The database tables have indexes for those queries

Answer (score 3):

I've been eying this for a few days now and finally am deciding to add my 2 cents worth.

I've been using FPM for a long time and it's a great thing but to get a scalable configuration with it is another story.  There's a whole lot that can be going wrong causing your problem but I have one suspicion.

I want to focus on the PHP errors showing up in your output because they indicate something is going wrong that shouldn't be.  I am wondering if, while you are clearing your cache and users browse the site, they are simultaneously pulling incomplete data because some information is deleted or in the process of being rebuilt.  You could even be seeing a situation where cache is being deleted, and new stuff is being cached at the same time.  I haven't looked at the CMS code for cache deletion but the PHP errors you showed seem to indicate some invalid data is being fetched in the process.

One thing to try would be to explicitly lock the tables before cache deletion and then release them.  This way, user's can't read or write data while things are being deleted.  In whatever script you call to clear the cache, try adding a query `LOCK TABLES articles WRITE, othertable WRITE, anyothertable WRITE`.  This will prevent other sessions (users) from reading or updating those tables while the cache is being cleared.

Users are impatient, if they try to load a page and it doesn't give them any feedback, they often try to reload, or go back and click other links.  This can cause the number of FPM processes to increase.  If 10 users refresh 5 times, you now have 50 extra processes running and also hanging making things worse.

-- Other stuff

Increase [ProxyTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout) or Timeout in Apache.  If you have a script that can run for a while, Apache will terminate the connection if it doesn't get any data back in a certain amount of time (which can be okay).  If it takes 5 minutes to clear the cache and nothing is sent back by PHP until it finishes, and Apache has a timeout of 120 seconds, it will drop the connection before it completes resulting in a timeout like you are seeing.  I have many sites that can do things for up to 10 minutes, so my Timeout in Apache is 600 seconds.  This allows the PHP requests to finish without things breaking.

Something else I noticed is that you are using unix domain sockets for FPM communication.  This can be okay, but they don't scale well on very busy sites.  I'd suggest using a TCP socket instead.  `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`  You'll then need to modify Apache to connect using tcp instead of a domain socket.

Set `listen.backlog` so connections can be queued when busy.  You'll probably also need to adjust the kernel value `net.core.somaxconn` using sysctl since it's usually pretty low.

Apache MPM: Switch to MPM [worker](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/worker.html) if you aren't using it already.  Since you're using FPM, worker is a very efficient MPM for Apache, much better than prefork (often the default).  Make sure to tune it to your needs (i.e. settings servers, threads, and MaxRequestWorkers appropriately).

-- Closing

I don't think there's anything too complicated going on here, the first thing I would look at is ensuring a cache delete can finish uninterrupted.  Even if this means users see a maintenance page for a couple minutes or their requests are blocked for a short time until it completes, if it avoids 500's and errors it's a small price to pay.

I honestly think there is a problem with deleting the cache and people browsing that is affecting the process and making things take longer than necessary or break.

Let me know if you have any questions or feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have plenty of RAM available (like over 16GB available), I'd suggest you are running out of resources and this is causing the 500 error.

Your configuration is saying that you can spawn up to 150 PHP-FPM processes and each one can use 256MB of memory — this alone enables the PHP-FPM server to use over 38GB of memory, and if that's not available, it will cause the 500 error.

Calculate what each server can use of memory, and then set it properly. Does this CMS need up to 256MB of memory? Could it run with fewer memory (like 32MB)? If MySQL, Apache and Nginx are in this same server, separate the memory each one will use, then set the proper value for `pm.max_children` and `php_value[memory_limit]`.

Please note that the lack of resources is system-wide, so if your PHP process uses all the memory available, MySQL might end up crashing for running out of resources (this might be the reason for the record not found).

If you can say how much memory you have available, I can help you out in configuring these numbers.

It'd be also good to know how much memory is available before you issue cache deletion and how much is available while it is running — it might be indeed using too much memory and suffocating the other processes (and if it uses PHP-CLI, it may have no memory limit).

Comment: For the sake of security, it'd be good to also lower these numbers: `php_value[upload_max_filesize]`, `php_value[max_post_size]`, `php_value[max_execution_time]` — unless you expect to receive big file uploads (up to 128MB), because that will be added on top of `memory_limit`, and may render your site very susceptible to DoS attacks.

Comment: Realistically though, idle FPM processes will consume much less memory (5-15MB) and ones in use possibly 15-50 but rarely more unless there is a lot of data involved.  Still a good point though.  The number of servers should be set such that it doesn't exceed the amount of memory in the server considering other things that are running as well (MySQL, Apache etc).

Answer (score -1):

Every time the server hangs up you can see a different error if php and/or Apache reach them limits.

If your host is Unix/Linux, could you check the results of command `$ top` while the CMS is doing any of hard jobs?

If you see the memory exhausted, a big part of swap memory filled and the CPU at top, try to adjust the memory_limit of php.ini to distribute the resources. But probably you need increase the resources, memory and CPU.

If memory and CPU are not busy, may be you have assigned less memory as expected to php. You could run more php-fpm workers, inrease memory limit per process,... see  http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/02/17/how-to-reduce-php-fpm-php5-fpm-ram-usage-by-about-50/. Also take a look to the Apache memory and CPU configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have enough free resources. I already checked top and nothing wrong was there

Comment: Ok, so reviewing the PHP warning, it seems that the article_id 1181 does not exist. May be every php-fpm worker hangs up in redaxo/include/classes/class.ooarticle.inc.php:44, waiting up to limit of 180 seconds. Here http://pastebin.com/4GniWSiJ an example of how to avoid the error and log context information about the exception in class.ooarticle.inc.php:44 for Redaxo 4.6.2. Replace the file to get log and to check if the leak really starts in this exception. You should restore the original file after.

Comment: Hey. I checked the database for the article with the id `1181`, but I have to tell you that it exists. Do you still think it has something to do with it?

Comment: Could you make a duplicate of your website and db and replace the pastebin file for the original to see: is 1181 missing again? is there any other id?

Comment: A lot of times an error on application overloads the memory or spending time and causes php workers hanging up. Increase the resources or an optimal configuration could bypass the leak but fixing the application is the best solution.

Comment: I checked and the id seems to be pretty random. I think it's because after the server error, when the script continues again, it doesn't know the previous index. But that means that the error happens before the id was not found

Comment: I'm debugging the Redaxo deleting cache function and never goes by class.ooarticle.inc.php:44. Deleting cache functionality deletes files on /redaxo/include/generated directory. May be you have a problem with the permissions if this function makes you an error.